# How to convert JSON/xml data to any other readable format

Tags: python, full-text-search, google-places-api

url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=%.7f,%.7f&radius=500&types=food|cafe&keyword=vegetarian&key=API_KEY'%(latitude,longitude)

resp = urllib.urlopen(url)

a =resp.read()

print a

How can I read output of this print statement, Is there any other way to convert it into readable format.thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'readable format'?

Comment: I am getting..location,lat ,lng,place_id,reference as output but I want location_name(in string) as a output.it is clear

Comment: Radar Search doesn't return place names.  To get those either 1) use Nearby Search which does (but returns fewer results), or 2) make Place Details requests with the Place IDs in the Radar Search response to fetch the names of those places.

Comment: I am using Radar Search, but I am not able to fetch the of the city.......

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem you are having?  If it's how to get the names of places from Radar Search, then as I said the solution is to make separate Place Details requests for those places. If that's not the issue, or that solution doesn't work for you, please explain why so we can help you.